# Why isn't this LESS mixin working?

Tags: syntax, less, mixins

```
.v-centered (@height,@width) {
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: (@height / 2)px 0 0 (@width / 2)px;
}
```

I am trying to make a LESS mixin for vertically centering things (the non-line-height way) -- and this LESS mixin isn't working. I have a feeling it has to do with my `margin: (@height / 2)px 0 0 (@width / 2)px;` line but I can't see where I'm going wrong in my syntax. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're using it. Right now your code assumes the width and height are passed in without units, but your `width` and `height` properties don't also append a unit like your `margin` property.

Also, to correctly center you want to negate your margins.

```
.v-centered (@height, @width) {
    width: @width;
    height: @height;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -(@height / 2) 0 0 -(@width / 2);
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqGLD)</kbd>

Comment: So with your method there, this would work? `.v-centered(200px,500px);`